# How to explain "content been cut off" effect in mac Chrome Browser in fullPage.js section scrolling behavior?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, scroll, compatibility, fullpage.js

Here is the Issue triggered seems only in **desktop mac chrome** browser currently. 
preview image:
[image]

[The issure Url](http://phantom.solstice.sg/debugging/case-content-cutoff-onmac-chrome/elf.solstice.sg/tateanzur.1.html#AWARDS)

Page framework used:
bootstrap3 , fullPage.js, jquery and no more;

Reproducing steps of this issue: 
using **desktop mac chrome** browser scroll up and down for several times, and will eventually see the text being cut off in this scrolling section (red boxes parts invisible), however, this didn't appear when you enter hashtag url autoscroll to this section when the page is first loaded on Mac chrome browser.

Currently as my test result:

- desktop windows chomre, windows safari, windows firefox,
- desktop mac firefox,mac safari,
- ipad chrome, ipad safari,
- samsung, iphone all default browser or chrome

all above browsers won't appear this issue;

Anyone has any ideas to explain this issue? 
why mac chrome renders differently and the weird visible/invisible effect (to viewer is invisible but to chrome console the "computed css value shows visible" and  there is not css overflow:hidden detected in it's parent container ), and as long as i turn **desktop  Mac chrome** inspect element console on and edit any css inside invisible part, all become normal and visible again.)

Comment: anyone using macbook chrome browser can take a look and kindly help me a bit on this issue ? thanks so much.

Comment: Not sure why, but maybe because you are using `display:table`in the `:before` element.

Answer (score 0):

You can init fullPage.js option

```
autoScrolling: true,
```

then The issue won't happen in mac chrome, but if you set it to false, this bug will still appear.

My default scroll setting is

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    anchors: ['HOME', 'ABOUT', 'SERVICES', 'WORKS', 'AWARDS','CONTACTS'],
    menu: '#myMenu',
    css3: false,
    scrollingSpeed: 700,
    autoScrolling: false,//if set True, scroll invisible bug will not come out.
    scrollOverflow: false,
    easing: 'easeInQuart',
    easingcss3: 'ease',
    loopBottom: false,
    loopTop: false,
    loopHorizontal: false,
    continuousVertical: false,
    fixedElements:'.header',             
    touchSensitivity: 5,
    normalScrollElementTouchThreshold: 15,    
 });
```